# jQuery Spritely and Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am using the excellent [jQuery Spritely](http://spritely.net/) for [this website](http://koodoocreative.co.uk/~stagesca/)

The problem I am having is the animation of the helicopter in Google Chrome. It works fine in IE7, 8, 9 and FF Up to V10.

I am using this line of code to get the helicopter to follow a line :

```
$("#helicopter").sprite({fps: 1, no_of_frames: 1})  
        .spRandom({  
            top: 5,  
            left: 800,  
            right: 800,  
            bottom: 10,  
            speed: 20000
});
```

The helicopter goes from right to left across in a forward direction in all browsers except for chrome. - In chrome it goes backwards, Which is quite puzzling as I thought Chrome renderred similar to FF?

Any help on this one is much appreciated, as I am at my wits end trying to solve it.

Comment: This looks like it is working to me.

Comment: @StuBlackett: Is your problem solved? Do you find solution yourself? Don't keep question unanswered. Post your solution or accept answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. Yes I did solves this.

What I did in the end was I came up with a quick fix in that I flipped the image of the helicopter and sent it in the other direction. As you can probably see from the example url.

Cheers

Comment: But on all our machines it was working fine. What was browser incompatible issue was? Can you give that code which was affecting?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk No, I had changed the code to suit. It definitley wasnt working. The effect was the plane would be flying backwards from the left

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine in all browsers. No need to change any code.

Your chrome copy might have some problem. Reinstall chrome again or repair it if possible and check again.